# Hologram Questions

Tags: optics, visible-light, hologram, parallax

How does a hologram create parallax, compared to a photograph? If a hologram's purpose is to reproduce the light field, what part of that field creates parallax (angle, magnitude or position)?

Answer (score 1):

Angle and position of light rays produce parallax.  Magnitude does not.  Parallax is the relative shift of apparent position or angle of two objects at different distances from the observer, as the observer moves in a direction perpendicular to the line from the observer to the objects.

Because a hologram accurately recreates the light field reaching the hologram from the objects, an observer looking through the hologram sees the objects as if they are really there.  So, moving side to side, the observer sees the same parallax as he/she would see if looking at the actual objects from the same positions.